# Changing [2,4] into [0,1,0,0,0,1] in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math-software

Good day,
I apologize for the very vague title, I didn't really know how to formulate what I want. However, I can explain what I mean:

I have a vector v1:

```
v1 = [n1, n2, n3, .... ni]
```

And I want to create a new vector from this

```
g1 = [n1-1 zero's, 1, n2-1 zeros, 1, ... ni-1 zeros, 1]
```

Now, I don't really know where to begin with this. I suppose for the zero's I can just use the command zeros(1,ni-1), but then I don't even know where to begin in imlementing this in Matlab in order to create g1.

I do of course know that the length of g1 will be equal to sum(v1). I suppose maybe it'll have to be some sort of double for loop?

I understand that I'm not giving you much, but I hope that maybe someone could give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following way :

```
g1 = zeros([1 sum(v1)]) ;   % this is as you said 

for i = 1:size(v1,2)
    temp = v1(1:i)    ;
    g1(sum(temp)) = 1 ;         % only index those numbers which you want to set 1
end
```

Comment: Man, it's amazing how simple things can be sometimes. Very efficient. Thank you very much!

Comment: wait there is a little mistake let me update it !

Comment: now its working !

Comment: Haha, indeed. It seemed correct, and then I tested it and realized that it wasn't putting the sequences after each other, but instead putting the 1's at the values of v1(i). But you took care of that :)

Comment: (fyi I've rolled back your change to the title of the question: backquotes don't seem to work in titles)

Comment: @TooTone I see I thought this would work as in case of stackoverflow but here it didn't

Comment: yes it's bizarre what works on one site and doesn't work on another.

Answer (score 4):

```
% Try the following
% Tested on GNU Octave, but should work on Matlab

v1 = [2,4] ;
g1 = [] ; 

for k=1:1:length(v1)
    g1 = [g1 zeros(1,v1(1,k)-1) 1] ;
end ;
```

Comment: This also works, and is even shorter! :) Thanks

Comment: No problem. Either solution works - choose whichever one you feel like using.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab it's better to [avoid loops](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). That way code runs faster and it's easier to write and read. In this case you can achieve your desired result in one line using [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
g1(cumsum(v1)) = 1;
```

Note that Matlab automatically fills with zeros. That's why I don't need to initialize `g1`.

Comment: Having said you don't need to initialise, it can be more efficient to allocate the memory first and then index using array notation.